# Larger height for portrait orientation Screen

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, landscape-portrait

I'm using visual studio 2010 to make a program for a portrait oriented computer monitor. The issue I'm running into is my landscape oriented development computer won't let me change the value of the form height higher than 1092. What do I do about this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Location` of the control(s) in the Properties window?  You should be able to place a control anywhere, even outside the bounds of the form as defined by its `Size`.

Comment: I have not, but there must be a better way than that.

Comment: If you can't drag them then the alternative to using the Properties window would be magic.

Comment: I was able to work around this issue, by turning my monitor on its side and switching the orientation of the screen, but this just seems silly. I literally have the monitor resting on it's side, and have it taped down with box tape to prevent it from sliding out and falling on it's back.

Comment: There are a number of Dell monitors in particular that support pivoting.  I have two at work and also two at home until one of them died recently.  Perhaps it's time for you to invest in one.  It's always better to develop in an environment that matches what you intend to deploy to as much as possible.

Comment: I mostly disagree. What the program actually looks like is such a small portion of the software. The real meat of it is in the code, and that has nothing to do with the orientation of the screen.